# Having trouble getting value for sum(filter with OR condition in google sheets

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, filter, sum

```
    =sum(filter(B:B,if(or(C:C="foo",C:C="bar"),A1>D1,A1<E1))
```

This returns no value.

```
    =sum(B:B,if(or(C:C="foo",C:C="bar"),A1>D1,A1<E1))
```

This is returning a sum, but looks to be ignoring the ,A1>D1,A1<E1)) criteria.

```
     A    B    C     D     E
 #1 Jan1  1   foo  Jan2  Jan3
 #2 Jan2  1   foo  Jan2  Jan3
 #3 Jan7  3   bar  Jan4  Jan9
 #4 Jan7  3   bar  Jan5  Jan9

=sum(B:B,if(or(C:C="foo",C:C="bar"),A1>D1,A1<E1))

This should return 6
```

Comment: *"This is throwing errors."*: where? Is this Excel? Google sheets? What is the minimal data needed in the sheet to reproduce the problem? What is the expected result for that data?

Comment: It's google sheets. Looking to return sum for A:A with all the criteria met...there should be a result that meets all the conditions but it is producing no result.

Comment: Sample input and corresponding expected output?

Comment: sry have to edit quickly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `OR` function is an [aggregate function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aggregate_function), i.e. it doesn't evaluate the conditions by row, replace it with the `+` operator.

```cpp
=SUM(FILTER(B:B,IF((C:C="foo")+(C:C="bar"),A:A>D:D,A:A<E:E)))
```

You can also replace `SUM(FILTER())` with `SUMPRODUCT()`

```cpp
=SUMPRODUCT(B:B,IF((C:C="foo")+(C:C="bar"),A:A>D:D,A:A<E:E))
```

Comment: Thanks, that works but it seems to be ignoring the A:A>D:D,A:A<E:E))) criteria

Comment: I tested it on my sheet and it's not ignoring it. Please reproduce the issue in a sample sheet and share the link with EDITOR rights.

Comment: I broke it down and it is working properly with the code you provided so something else is the culprit....ok found it. I had the wrong range for the dates. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

*You may try:*

```js
=sum(ifna(filter(B:B,regexmatch(C:C,"foo|bar"),A:A>D:D,A:A<E:E)))
```

***OR***

```js
=sum(ifna(filter(B:B,(C:C="foo")+(C:C="bar"),A:A>D:D,A:A<E:E)))
```